# Why does this program print "Hello"? (how is a function pointer translated to Runnable.run() in Java)

Tags: java, java-8

The following sample program prints `Hello`.  the method `exampleMethod(Runnable toRun)` has a Runnable type parameter. The function pointer `MyTest::sayHello` does not have a run method. How is it got executed?

```
public class MyTest {

    // Method that takes a "method" as argument
    static void exampleMethod(Runnable toRun) {
        toRun.run();
    }

    // Method to pass
    static void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        exampleMethod(MyTest::sayHello);  // prints "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no pointers in Java (at least none accessible to the programmer). The syntax is - for now - just syntactic sugar for an anonymous interface implementation.

Comment: Alternative, you can say, the way Java introduced function types so far, is by always converting them to a particular interface type, which must be a *functional interface* which has a congruent method. Here, `void run()` and `void sayHello()` have congruent function types, hence, it is possible to implement `Runnable` by letting its `run()` method invoke `sayHello()`.

Comment: @Turing85 "*The syntax is - for now - just syntactic sugar*" This is not accurate, otherwise the stack traces in this example would be identical https://ideone.com/jZzE3i

Answer (score 1):

The code inside the main method is same as:

```
Runnable runnable = () -> {
MyTest.sayHello();
};

exampleMethod(runnable);
```